# Login with Python into a Website

Tags: python, authentication, web

im currently trying to login to my account at ds-exchange (https://app.ds-exchange.co.uk/#/login/signin) via Python (Dont ask why, im just testing what i can do with Paython currently since im learning it :P )

I've checked a bit how their login works with Fiddler:

1. They do an empty post @ https://api.ds-exchange.co.uk/v1/get/ip/
2. They do post device_id, app_type, platform, app_version & identifier which they've got from step 1. @ https://api.ds-exchange.co.uk/v1/device/register/
3. Now they post email, password(in sha256) and access_token @ https://api.ds-exchange.co.uk/v1/login/

I've rewrite it simply in Python:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

#disable ssl warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

payload = {}
content = requests.post('https://api.ds-exchange.co.uk/v1/get/ip/', verify=False, params=payload)

print(content.text)


payload = {'device_id': '123123123123123', 'app_type': 'admin', 'platform': 'web', 'app_version': '2.0.1', 'identifier': '127.0.0.1'}
content = requests.post('https://api.ds-exchange.co.uk/v1/device/register/', verify=False, params=payload)

print(content.text)
answer = json.loads(content.text)
print(answer['data']['access_token'])

accesstoken = answer['data']['access_token']

payload = {'email': 'dolemites@test.de', 'password': 'dolemites', 'access_token': accesstoken}
content = requests.post('https://api.ds-exchange.co.uk/v1/login/', verify=False, params=payload)

print(content.text)
```

That are the answers i got from python script:

Step 1: `{"ts":1534762909,"success":true,"error":false,"data":{"ip_address":"::1"}}`

Step 2: `{"ts":1534762911,"success":true,"error":false,"data":{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl9pZHMiOiIyZTAxZmI0MDUyZTEyZjdmMzU2OTliZWVmODU3Zjk2MTY5ODBmMDA0MDMwOTFmM2M3OTk3NzdhYzRjZDM0YTEyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM0NzYyOTExLCJleHAiOjE1MzQ4NDkzMTEsImF1ZCI6ImNyeXB0b2JhbmsuY29tIiwiaXNzIjoiY3J5cHRvYmFuay5jb20ifQ.aYAcdRmYdRPxYtylh17gYJKjXYKiRhWlWRg-JnmFYBw"}}`

Step 3: `{"ts":1534762912,"success":false,"error":true,"error_msg":"Access Denied. Token not found","logout":true}`

The problem is that im getting a completly different answer in Fiddler in step 3, im getting there this: "error_msg": "dolemites@test.de is not found"

What im doing wrong? :(

Comment: Im guessing that the email isn't found

Comment: You didnt understand; Step 3: {"ts":1534762912,"success":false,"error":true,"error_msg":"Access Denied. Token not found","logout":true} is the error i'm getting, but i want this one: "error_msg": "dolemites@test.de is not found"
I know i've entered an wrong email, it's just to test :)
When im getting "error_msg": "dolemites@test.de is not found" im also able to insert the real account to login

Comment: First i tried to post directly to https://app.ds-exchange.co.uk/#/login/signin but im getting a 405 error, that's why im trying now their api

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **selenium** library, this is used for make unittest.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a comment/suggestion than an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry I have not the necesary reputation to do comments